Match comma-separator, excluding comma between digits
The task is to match, if string contains commas, with exception of commas, which separate 2 digits.
For example, this address
132 My Street Bigtown BG2A 4,5 England

must not be matched, because it contains comma, but this comma separate 4 and 5 - digits.
And this one:
132, My Street, Bigtown, BG2A 4,5, England

must be matched, because it contains comma, which not only separate digits, but also digit and char ("132, My Street..."), digit and char ("...5, England").
Simply put, other examples:
Expressions:
 s,d,1,1
 1,s,1,1
 s,s,f,f
 1,s,1,2
 s,1,s,1
 s,1,1,s

must be matched
And:
 111,111
 1,2,3,4
 mm 1,1
 sfvdfv1,2

must not be matched
My decision is:
^.*[1-9]((,|, )[a-zA-Z]).*$|^.*[a-zA-Z]((,|, )[1-9]).*$|^.*[a-zA-Z]((,|, )[a-zA-Z]).*$

This regex consists of 3 parts, conjunct by logical "Or" (|):
 ^.*[1-9]((,|, )[a-zA-Z]).*$

match comma between any digit and any char
 ^.*[a-zA-Z]((,|, )[1-9]).*$

match comma between any char and any digit
^.*[a-zA-Z]((,|, )[a-zA-Z]).*$

match comma between any char and any other char
This works. But expression seems to be bulky, hard to read and logical redundant generally.
I also looked towards something like:
^.*(,|, ).*$&^.*[^[1-9]((,|, )[1-9])].*$

I expected,  ^.(,|, ).$ match comma between any tokens and  ^.[^[1-9]((,|, )[1-9])].$ not match commas between digits. So it must any commas except commas, which separate 2 digits.
But this one does not work.

(,|, ) can be simplified to , ? (comma followed by an optional space).

Can you post all the test cases along with the expected result (match or no match)?

I use (,|, ) as comma may be accompanied by space, or not be accompanied

Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Addresses

I updated my question with a set of test cases

Try: ^(?=.*(?: \D+\s*){1,},).*$?

user24714692. This works ) Could you, please, explain, how this works?

@Jelly Added an answer. ^(?=.*(?:\D+\s*),).*$ is a more strict pattern. ^(?=.*(?: \D+\s*){1,},).*$ is less strict.

You can try:
^(?=.*(?:\D+\s*),).*$


(?=.*(?:\D+\s*),): means it must have at least a group of (?:\D+\s*), in the string.

\D means non digit chars are allowed as opposed to \d.


Matches:
 s,d,1,1
 1,s,1,1
 s,s,f,f
 1,s,1,2
 s,1,s,1
 s,1,1,s

and does not match:
 111,111
 1,2,3,4
 mm 1,1
 sfvdfv1,2



You can make your pattern more strict, such as using:
^(?=.*[^\d\s]+,).*$

Note

^(?=.*[^\d\s]+,).*$ simply means you must have at least one [^\d\s]+ non-digit, non-space char followed by one comma in your address.

(?:) stands for a non-capture memory-efficient group.

[^\d\s]+ one or more non-digit, non-space chars



Why not simply ^.*\D\s*,.*$? https://regex101.com/r/AFvMAf/1

@Dogbert That's better.

You could match a line that contains a non whitspace char other than a comma followed by a comma, or the other way around:
^.*?(?:[^\d\s]\s*,|,\s*[^\d\s]).*

The pattern matches:

^ Start of string
.*? Match any character, as few as possible
(?: Non capture group for 2 alternatives

[^\d\s]\s*, Match a non whitespace except for a digit followed by optional whitespace chars and a comma
| Or
,\s*[^\d\s] The previous pattern, the other way around


) Close the non capture group
.* Match the rest of the line

See a regex demo.

If you don't want to cross newlines (as \s can match a newline)
^.*?(?:[^\d\s][^\S\n]*,|,[^\S\n]*[^\d\s]).*

See another regex demo
